# Problem with table structure when scraping data using selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap data from clinicaltrials.gov! my code doesn't give the desired result all the time, depending on the link, sometimes, I get the correct table, sometimes I don't.

Example :

url =  "https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=Activated+Protein+C+Resistance"

url = "https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=%22Abortion%2C+Incomplete%22"

When I use my code on the first link, I get a correct table but when I use it on the second one, the table I get has a messy structure where the column Locations is repeated multiple times as a row like the following table

```
    Row Saved   Status      Study Title   Conditions Interventions  Locations
0   1   NaN     Completed   Pilot Survey  Arbovirus  NaN            NaN
1   Locations: Tropical Medicine centerKaohsiung c...   Locations: Tropical Medicine centerKaohsiung c...   Locations: Tropical Medicine centerKaohsiung c...   Locations: Tropical Medicine centerKaohsiung c...   Locations: Tropical Medicine centerKaohsiung c...   Locations: Tropical Medicine centerKaohsiung c...   NaN
```

here's my code if you want to reproduce the results :

```
import time
import selenium 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ser = Service("/xxxxxxx/chromedriver") # change it to where your chromedriver is 
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)


    
url = "https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=%22Abortion%2C+Incomplete%22"

#select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('theDataTable_length'))
#select.select_by_value('100')
time.sleep(1)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

list_table = []
#df_tables = pd.read_html(str(soup), flavor="bs4")
df_tables = pd.read_html(str(soup))[1]
list_table.append(df_tables)

xp_next = '//*[@id="theDataTable_next"]/span'

while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[class='paginate_button next']")))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xp_next).click()
        html = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        df_tables = pd.read_html(str(soup))[1]
        #display(df_tables)
        list_table.append(df_tables)
        print("Navigating to Next Page")
        time.sleep(1)
    except (TimeoutException, WebDriverException) as e:
        print("Last page reached")
        break
        
driver.quit()

df = pd.concat(list_table)
df
```

what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    data = {
        "draw": "1",
        "start": "0",
        "length": "100",
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=data).json()
    for i in r['data']:
        pp(i)
        exit()


main('https://www.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/rpc/Ti0yqBc9u64WpV7yZwUPedcOvnjzuBc9mwhazih8p')
```

Output:

```
['<a id="rowId1"></a>1',
 'NCT00670761',
 '<span style="color:#E60000;">Completed</span>',
 '<a title="Show study NCT00670761: Misoprostol for the Treatment of '
 'Incomplete Abortion" '
 'href="/ct2/show/NCT00670761?cond=%22Abortion%2C+Incomplete%22&amp;draw=1&amp;rank=1">Misoprostol '
 'for the Treatment of <span class="hit_syn">Incomplete Abortion</span></a>',
 '<ul><li><span class="hit_inf">Abortion, Incomplete</span></li></ul>',
 '<ul><li>Drug: misoprostol</li><li>Procedure: MVA</li></ul>',
 'Interventional<br/>',
 'Not Applicable',
 '<ul><li>Gynuity Health Projects</li><li>Befelatanana Maternity '
 'Centre</li><li>Municipal Clinical Hospital No. 1</li><li>(and 7 '
 'more...)</li></ul>',
 'Other',
 '<ul><li>Allocation: Randomized</li><li>Intervention Model: Parallel '
 'Assignment</li><li>Masking: None (Open Label)</li><li>Primary Purpose: '
 'Treatment</li></ul>',
 '<ul><li>complete resolution of signs/symptoms of incomplete abortion without '
 'recourse to surgery at any point for any reason</li></ul>',
 '720',
 'Female',
 '18 Years and older \xa0 (Adult, Older Adult)',
 'NCT00670761',
 '2.2.1',
 '',
 'July 2004',
 'April 2010',
 'December 2010',
 'May 2, 2008',
 'July 27, 2016',
 '',
 '<ul><li>H&#244;pital de District Sanitaire Dand&#233;<br/>Bobo Dioulasso, '
 'Burkina Faso</li><li>H&#244;pital de District Sanitaire de '
 'Ziniar&#233;<br/>Ouagadougou, Burkina Faso</li><li>Befelatanana Maternity '
 'Centre<br/>Antananarivo, Madagascar</li><li>(and 3 more...)</li></ul>',
 '']
```